# Series ImageButton Highlighted

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

I have series of images like `redo, undo, choose, delete`. I need to understand how to implement when user clicks on `redo` and it will highlight. When user click on `undo`, then `redo` button goes back to default state and undo button highlighted.

I have the following implementation for `redo` button

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:state_enabled="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/redo_off" />
  <item
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/redo_on" />
  <item
      android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/redo_on" />
  <item
      android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/redo_off" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to set the desired state of these buttons in their respective click listeners. Not sure if this can be done via `selector` xml files.

Comment: Yes, it must be in the click listeners.

Answer (score 0):

here's the trick 
make a method toggle and pass the int value like this

```
private void toggleButton(int value){
switch(value){
case 1:
//set enabled background color of the redo button
//set disabled background color of the undo button
//set disabled background color of the choose button
//set disabled background color of the delete button
break;
case 2:
//set disabled background color of the redo button
//set enabled background color of the undo button
//set disabled background color of the choose button
//set disabled background color of the delete button
break;
case 3:
//set disabled background color of the redo button
//set disabled background color of the undo button
//set enabled background color of the choose button
//set disabled background color of the delete button
break;
case 4:
//set disabled background color of the redo button
//set disabled background color of the undo button
//set disabled background color of the choose button
//set enabled background color of the delete button
break;
}
}
```

onYour button click add call this method
if you click on redo button call

```
toggleButton(1);
```

if you click on undo button call

```
toggleButton(2);
```

if you click on choose button call

```
toggleButton(3);
```

if you click on delete button call

```
toggleButton(4);
```